# Does Aptana Studio change/format files during deploy? Getting 500 error without changes

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

Using Aptana Studio 3. Does anyone know if Aptana Studio formats or changes files when it does an "auto deploy"?

Didn't make any changes to files while I ported over a Wordpress site to Aptana Studio. When I set up an SFTP connection and enabled auto deploy, it did what looked like a sync and suddenly the server crashed with a 500 error.

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()
```

Given the error above, it looks like Aptana deleted something. Is there a local history like IntelliJ?

I'm hoping someone can explain if Aptana formats files or deletes them when it does a sync.

Thanks.

Comment: I think its not an *Aptana* issue. Its more like an *FTP* connection issue. May be some bytes or some files is missed while uploading.

Comment: Agreed I wish I had version control on this. It's a side project LOL. Thanks for pointing out some files may be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana won't delete anything during a sync...but it does do a "safe" upload. It uploads the new file to a temporary file on the server, deletes the original file, and then renames the new one to the old one. The main reason this fails is if there is a mismatch in server permissions such that it can't perform the rename or delete. Fixing those permissions fixes the issue.

As to Local History...try this: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm

Comment: Ah interesting so there is a local history. I'll be honest it was impossible to find. It turned out it wasn't a permissions issue though but I'll accept this answer since it does prevent future headaches ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a very strange result after the Aptana "auto deploy". Essentially, all of the files in the folder under editing were copied and overwritten to the root.

Given the circumstances it looks like an Aptana bug. I double-checked connection settings and folders were set correctly. Perhaps a sign to abandon Aptana.

Comment: So you are editing file /a/b/c.txt (assume /a is the root of the site) and c.txt is saved to /a/c.txt?

Comment: Exactly, and after looking into it I figured out why. The connection manager was ignoring my project root and was instead assuming the root was the folder I was editing. A terrible feature since it created a huge headache. Not sure why it does that.

Comment: Hi DeLonge, I tested on the latest 3.0.7 release, followed the steps to set up the connection and allow it to auto-deploy any changes, then edit a local file under a subfolder of the project, and it's uploaded correctly. Could you check what version of Studio do you have? Also are there any other plugins you have installed? Want to see what difference we have in your scenario where the problem occurs. Thanks.

Comment: More than happy to help. It's a fresh install v3.0.7 and the exact steps were this: 1) created a new project 2) right-clicked on the folder I wanted to deploy 3) created a new SFTP connection and defined the project root on the server 4) chose autodeploy and "1-way computer to server"

Comment: It seems that Aptana chose the folder as the root of the connection. Maybe a bug or a "feature". Either way it wasn't the expected behaviour. This did occur twice with two folders on separate occasions until I defined the connection using the deploy icon instead of the context menu. Thanks for looking into it.